# Slow performance of: Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract::getSortedAttributes

Tags: performance

Hi we are seeing some slow performance in "Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract::getSortedAttributes"

I was reading this (from 2 years ago and Mage 1.6). Would this still apply?

http://blog.nexcess.net/2012/04/16/simple-magento-sort-optimization-patch/

Comment: the code is the same as before, even on version 1.9, you can check magento's code